# Communication with usbserialhost to Android

Tags: java, android, android-usb

I am new to android programming smart card detection (read). We have RFC card reader(RFID-RC522) connected to the android device using otg cable. RFC Card reader is detected using usb-serial port api, but unable to read card from RFC card reader. We have implemented card reading in java but unable to implement in android.

1) How to get port number equivalent to windows COM ports

2) If it is not possible, how can I communicate using connection.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT, 0x00, 0x0000, 0, null, 0, 0); method

3) Java Code for Connecting Device

```
static int connect ( String portName ) throws IOException
{

     CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = null;


     try {
         portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
     } catch (NoSuchPortException e) {
         System.out.println("Port " + portName + " is not available");
     }
     if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
     {
         System.out.println("Error: Port " + portName + " is currently in use");
     }
     else
     {
         CommPort commPort = null;
         try {
             commPort = portIdentifier.open(portName,2000);
         } catch (PortInUseException e) {
             System.out.println("Error: Port " + portName + " is currently in use");
         }
         System.out.println("Info: Port Availble "+portName);
         if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
         {
             SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
             try {
                 serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
             } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                 System.out.println("Error: Port " + portName + " is currently in use");
             }

             InputStreamIn = serialPort.getInputStream();
             OutputStreamOut = serialPort.getOutputStream();
             return 0;
         }
         else
         {
             //System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
             System.out.println("Error: Port " + portName + " is currently in use");
         }
     }    
     return -1;
 }
```

4) Please tell me how on android can I communicate like on java

Answer (score -1):

You have to use USB Host Android API:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html
 to enumerate devices, grant permission.

To communicate you could also use this API or there's also open-source library for usb-serial devices as this one: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

**UPDATE1**

For instance, in this lib, you have a class https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/usbSerialForAndroid/src/main/java/com/hoho/android/usbserial/driver/UsbSerialPort.java with read and write methods.

Comment: we have commands like this  static int PCD_IDLE     = 0x00; //NO action; cancel the current command;
 static int PCD_AUTHENT   = 0x0E; // authentication key;
 static int PCD_RECEIVE   = 0x08; // receive data;
 static int PCD_TRANSMIT   = 0x04; // Transmit Data;
 static int PCD_TRANSCEIVE  = 0x0C; // Send and receive data hwo to pass the commands using android pls tell me

Comment: pls give one example how to read it  static int PCD_IDLE = 0x00; using api

Comment: Pls help it is important for me

Comment: @ANANDPRABHAKAR, I'll not develop for you. You have to try and test by yourself. You have to read documentation of Android USB Host and usb-serial-for-android.

Comment: @ANANDPRABHAKAR, StackOverflow is not a commercial support. It's a community support !

Comment: kkk sir sorry to disturb you

Comment: @ANANDPRABHAKAR, Is it useful ?

Comment: Finally I have solved the hardware detection by using usb serial port

Comment: @ANANDPRABHAKAR Could you please give me some reference on hardware detection using USB Serial Port.